# Chi- square test or Mann Whitney test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, likert, contingency-tables

I have the following data:

group A: very bad 12, bad 20, quite good 11, good 29, very good 14
group B: very bad 20, bad 10, quite good 6, good 11, very good 34

1. which test is appropriate for this kind of data?
   I think the chi-square test is appropriate since it's nominal data.
2. could you apply the same test to these data in a different way?
   I built a 2x2 contingency table by grouping very bad and bad on the one hand, and  quite good, good and very good on the other hand.
3. if the chi square in 1. is significant an the chi square test in 2 is non significant, how would you intepret the results?
   I am not sure really.
4. Could you recode the data and apply a differnt test?
   I recoded the data as 5-point Likert scale and applied a Mann Whitney test.
5. If the Mann Whitney test is non significant how would you interpret this result compared to those of chi-square tests?
   I don't know.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help with this. I am not sure that the chi-square test is the right choice for 1 either. So if anyone had suggestions it would be helpful.