# Categorical ordinal data: which test is better?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, ordinal-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have the following data:

| Group | very bad | bad | quite good | good | very good |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 20 | 11 | 29 | 14 |
| B | 20 | 10 | 6 | 11 | 34 |

Group A receives training, group B doesn't

1. which test is appropriate for this kind of data?
2. could you apply the same test to these data in a different way?
3. if the chi square in 1. is significant and the chi square test in 2 is non significant, how would you interpret the results?
4. Could you recode the data and apply a different test?
5. If the Mann Whitney test is non significant how would you interpret this result compared to those of chi-square tests?

I would be very grateful if anyone could help with this!

Comment: Why you might do a chi-squared test of homogeneity is clear, and I get the P-value .025 < 5%. But residuals suggest no interesting _ad hoc_ tests. // Because samples A and B have different shapes, one would have to take a 2-sample Wilcoxon test as a test of 'domination' rather than a straightforward test for difference in medians, but I get P-value 0.78 (not significant). // As @Levian says in his answer (+1), the two tests are not equivalent in objective.  It really does come down to your purpose in comparing A and B.

Comment: It would help to edit your post to focus on a *single* question: as it stands, the five questions make it a little too broad to be appropriate here.

Comment: How's this different from that one? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/518692/chi-square-test-or-mann-whitney-test

Answer (score 2):

The chi-square test tests against the alternative that the distributions are different; the Mann-Whitney test tests against the alternative that one group is stochastically larger than the other. It depends on what you are interested in (i.e., if eventually you'd like to know whether one group is generally rating higher than the other, or whether they are different in any kind of way including the possibility that one group has the highest as well as the lowest ratings). In fact, the data look like distributions being different, but not like one is clearly stochastically larger than the other - group B seems to have a higher probability for both "very bad" and "very good" -, so it makes some sense that chi-squared is significant and Mann-Whitney isn't.

The data that you have are in fact ordinal, meaning that the information in them is not quantitative but can be ordered. The Mann-Whitney test will take the order into account, whereas the chi-squared test will not. Note that the standard form of the Mann-Whitney test assumes continuous quantitative observations, however most modern implementations can deal with ties that occur in discrete variables like yours.

I don't see any reason to group categories, as this reduces information. Why would you want to lose that information? (There may be reasons in specific situations, particularly with too small sample sizes and a large number of categories, but you should be just about OK with those you have.)

Generally one should decide what to test and how before seeing the data, because if you're playing around with various tests it is very easy to get confused by seemingly "contradictory" results. In fact, if for some reason you *wanted* to achieve significance, trying out a number of approaches would give you a bigger chance to find something significant even if in fact nothing is going on, opening the door to either cheating yourself or others (if you're testing at 5% level, every test has a 5% probability to come out significant in case that the null hypothesis is true, so with three tests that probability can be up to 15%, offering little protection against having a meaningless significance somewhere).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply - it's very helpful!

I've been given the data and questions as an exercise, but I am not sure what to do, so I'm trying different things to understand what works best.

I thought to group categories because the chi-square test tells me there's a difference, but not where this difference comes from. SO I thought that if I grouped the categories, re-run the test and got a significant result, it would tell me that one group prefers 'good' and the other prefers 'bad'.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a categorical variable measured for group A and B and you want to compare the groups.

1. You can use the qui-squared test with contingency tables to check if they are dependent.
2. Not sure what you mean
3. you have one output for the comparison of the 2 groups. If it's significant (p -value<0.05) group 1 and 2 are different and possibly independent.
4. Maybe. If you understand that is relevant.
5. Mann whitney test compares the measurements of a continuous variable among 2 groups. If it is significant means the difference is significant among groups. It is meaningless in your case since the variables are categorical.